# SQL Concat and convert date to MM/YYYY

Tags: sql, date, teradata

Newbie here. Thanking you in advance for your help!

I have the following code to count unique records based on 3 data elements:

`count(distinct concat(a.emp_nbr, b.acct_nbr, c.event_dt))`

The event_dt is stored in the db as [DATE].

the issue is that i don't want to EXCLUDE 'DD' in the concat match statement. I want to match based on the MM/YYYY only.  I believe the answer is to convert the [DATE] to MM/YYYY.

Ultimately i want to count distinct records based on emp_nbr, acct_nbr and mm/yyyy of event_dt.

Thanks!

MODIFIED

here is the query:

```
select distinct
B.emp_nbr, A.cust_nbr,  E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt, 
count(distinct concat(B.emp_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt))

from customer A

left join  user_profile B on A.owner_ID = B.owner_ID
left join account_owner E on A.cust_nbr = E.cust_nbr

where CAST(A.ramp_dt AS date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') between '01/01/2020' and '08/31/2020' 

group by 1,2,3,4
```

Here's a sample of the results that are returned:

ln...emp_nbr.....cust_nbr.....ctry_enti_nbr event_dt......'Unique Identifier'
1....123.........87543290......488807........5/15/2020.........1
2....123.........62524497......488807........2/28/2020.........1     **
3....123.........62524497......488807........2/26/2020.........1     **
4....789.........62524497......488807........2/26/2020.........1
5....876.........62524497......488807........2/26/2020.........1

Line 2 or 3 should NOT be flagged as '1' (unique)

EDIT:  changed code based on dnoeth's reco to add the count(*) OVER (PARTITION):

```
select distinct
    B.emp_nbr, A.cust_nbr,  E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt, 
    to_char(A.event_dt, 'YYYYMM') as Event_Month, 
    case when COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY B.emp_nbr, A.cntry_enti_nbr, Event_Month)
        = 1 then 1 else 0 end as Unique_Monthly_Event
    
    from customer A
    
    left join  user_profile B on A.owner_ID = B.owner_ID
    left join account_owner E on A.cust_nbr = E.cust_nbr
    
    where CAST(A.event_dt AS date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') between '01/01/2020' and '08/31/2020' 
    
    group by 1,2,3,4
```

works fine for the previous case, however in another case it shows all ZERO for unique:

ln...emp_nbr.....cust_nbr.....ctry_enti_nbr event_dt......'Unique Identifier'
1....123.........78473466......863429........5/31/2020.........0
2....123.........78473466......863429........5/29/2020.........0
3....123.........78473466......863429........5/5/2020..........0

I would like to see ONE record with a unique identifier of "1"

Comment: B.emp_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt are included in group by, too. Of course, this is useless. What exactly do you want combined into a single row using GROUP BY? Distinct records  by *what*?

Comment: @dnoeth ... Hi there...i want all records returned however, i want to know if a customer attended an event at least 1x in a given month.  I don't need to count ALL events.  If they attended 2 events in same month, as in sample-set 2 and 3, i only want to count 1.  

hope this makes some sort of sense :)

Essentially:
- pull list of all customers
- the employee assigned to them
- all of the event dates for, in this case, a year
- determine how many customers have an event date for a given month.
    o  I only want to count the unique instances not all events

Comment: @dnoeth ... i also tried FORMAT however didn't work.

count(distinct concat(E.cntry_enti_nbr, B.emp_nbr, format(A.event_dt), 'MMYYYY')) as Unique_Event

Comment: *Line 2 or 3 should NOT be flagged as '1' (unique)* Why, what's the logic behind? And what should be your final result?

Comment: @dnoeth Hi there!  Almost have it....see my revised post based on your recommendation to add the count(*) OVER (PARTITION).

in another case, I have 3 records....with 3 different event dates.  they are all returning '0' unique.....however I would like to see 1 record (perhaps the latest one) with a unique value of '1'

Comment: Edited my query to use ROW_NUMBER instead of COUNT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Line 2 or 3 should NOT be flagged as '1' (unique)

... because there's more than one row per *emp_nbr/cust_nbr/ctry_enti_nbr*?

Then you need a simple *Group Count*:

```
select
   B.emp_nbr, A.cust_nbr,  E.cntry_enti_nbr, A.event_dt, 
   -- I would like to see ONE record with a unique identifier of "1"
   -- this returns the row with the latest event date
   case 
     when row_number()
          over (partition by B.emp_nbr, A.cust_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr
                order by event_dt desc) = 1
     then 1
     else 0
   end

from customer A

left join  user_profile B on A.owner_ID = B.owner_ID
left join account_owner E on A.cust_nbr = E.cust_nbr

where CAST(A.ramp_dt AS date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') between '01/01/2020' and '08/31/2020' 

group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: hi there.  I am using A.event_dt in the count distinct statement not A.cust_nbr.

Comment: awesome, thank you!!!  i just had to remove the * in row_number....FROM row_number ('*') TO row_number()

Comment: Ops, the `*` was a left-over from count :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char()`.  Something like this:

```
count(distinct concat(a.emp_nbr, '|', b.acct_nbr, '|', to_char(c.event_dt, 'YYYYMM'))
```

or more commonly:

```
count(distinct a.emp_nbr || '|' || b.acct_nbr || '|' || to_char(c.event_dt, 'YYYYMM')
```

Note that this also puts a delimiter between

Your query looks off.  I think you just want:

```
select A.cust_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, to_char(c.event_dt, 'YYYYMM'),
      count(*)
from customer A left join
     user_profile B
     on A.owner_ID = B.owner_ID left join
     account_owner E
     on A.cust_nbr = E.cust_nbr
where CAST(A.ramp_dt AS date format 'MM/DD/YYYY') between '01/01/2020' and '08/31/2020' 
group by A.cust_nbr, E.cntry_enti_nbr, to_char(c.event_dt, 'YYYYMM');
```

Comment: hmmm... this didn't work either....same as other proposed solution, the same case with 2 records: same emp_nbr, same acct_nbr, with event in same MM/YYYY....both return count of 1 for each row

Comment: @tj919 . . . The `emp_nbr` or `acct_nbr` might look the same, but they would appear to be different.

Comment: ....Hello Gordon, they are actually 2 distinct values/columns from different tables....emp_nbr represents the employee, and acct_nbr is the customer's account number.

this is only an excerpt of the entire query.  what i am trying to determine is the unique # of instances where employee logged an event for the same customer, in the same month, then 1 of the rows/records should read '1' and the other row/record should read '0' or null

hopefully this makes sense @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Your group by #4 is on a date column, and unless the timestamps are identical, they would return as unique. I would start by trunc-ing the dates and changing the group by to go from largest group to smallest. Without having a copy of the data I can't confirm this though.

Comment: @Zynon Putney II ... hi there, would you kindly provide an example on 'tunc-ing the dates and grouping by largest to smallest?

Comment: select trunc(sysdate) from dual; And for the group by, just change the order of the columns. For example I would group by acct_nbr before emp_nbr. I also tend to put an order by statement with any group by statement so I can see more logically what's happening

Comment: @Zynon Putney II ... i have modified my original post to include a sample result set.

Comment: @ZynonPutneyII ... i also tried FORMAT however didn't work. count(distinct concat(E.cntry_enti_nbr, B.emp_nbr, format(A.event_dt), 'MMYYYY')) as Unique_Event

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... Hi Gordon.  Is it possible to keep the original date as well, and possibly add your "to_char(c.event_dt, 'YYYYMM')" as a new column?

not sure i understand how the 'count(*)' works.

Comment: @tj919 . . . You can add `min(c.event_dt)`.  But there are multiple dates, so it doesn't make sense "to keep it".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `EXTRACT()` function to extract year and month from the date. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.emp_nbr, b.acct_nbr, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM c.event_dt), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM c.event_dt)))
FROM ...
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working....i have a case with 2 records:  same emp_nbr, same acct_nbr, with event in same MM/YYYY....both return count of 1 for each row.

Comment: Then your GROUP BY is probably bad, please show the full query.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for your reply, i have modified my original post with the query as requested